# Opening PDF from angular blob in Internet explorer browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following server side code in web api

```
tempResponse = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
tempResponse.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
tempResponse.Content.Headers.Add(@"Content-type", "application/pdf");
tempResponse.Content.Headers.ContentType = new   
System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
tempResponse.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new 
System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("inline");
```

I am using angular JS and following is the code in my javascript file.

```
$http.post(apiURL + "/DownloadPdf", data, { responseType: 'arraybuffer'}, config)
.then(function (result) {
  var file = new Blob([result.data], { type: 'application/pdf' })
  var fileName = "CommissionStatement.pdf"

  if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    window.location.href = 'Assets/Document CheckList.pdf'
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, fileName)
  } else {
    var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file)
    window.open(window.location.href = 'Assets/Document CheckList.pdf', '_blank')
    window.open(objectUrl, '_blank')

    $window.location.href =
      window.location.protocol + "//" +
      window.location.host + "?BrokerId=" +
      AgentInfo.Data.BrokerId +
      "&OfficeCode=" +
      AgentInfo.Data.OfficeCode;
  }
});

console.log($scope.Result)
},
function (error) {
  $scope.Error = error.data
})
```

This blob opens fine in Google Chrome and FireFox. But IE will prompt for open or save. But I would like it to open in the browser. I would appreciate any input in making it open without prompting. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about just excluding the if/else statement and just open the ObjectURL in IE as well? Otherwise [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/) is a alternative if you want to render it in a browser using canvas

Another problem I see with your code is that you are trying to open up a new window with `window.open()` the problem is that they can become very easy blocked unless it happens within 1 sec after a user interaction event like onclick for example. A xhr.onload is not an user interaction event

So if you are experience some issue like that try doing something like

```
// Untested, just to give a ruffly idea
btn.onclick = () => {
  var win = window.open('', '_blank')
  win.document.body.innerHTML = 'loading...'
  $http.post(...).then(res => {
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    // redirect
    win.location.href = url
  })
}
```

Another thing. Why are you using `responseType = arrayBuffer`? you could set it to a blob directly...?